# AngularJs html metadata was changed by google storage

Tags: angularjs, templates, migration, google-cloud-storage

I have a plan to change the hosting of my angularJS static app from a S3 bucket to a GCS bucket. But I have some problems with the metadata of the html template files.

I have copied the files with the command `gsutil` and I have already set all files in the bucket with the `public_read` permission. Now I can access the `index.html` file and serve it with `text/html` content-type, but the template file metadata has been changed by google storage to `application/xml` and, when accessing it, the status code is 401.

```
Status Code: 401 Unauthorized
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Length: 131
Content-Type: application/xml; charset=UTF-8
Date: Thu, 24 May 2018 03:44:21 GMT
Expires: Thu, 24 May 2018 03:44:21 GMT
Server: UploadServer
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="https://accounts.google.com/"
```

Sometime it works and sometime it doesn't. What can I do in this situation?

Comment: What do you mean by 'sometime it works and sometime it doesn't'? Have you tried to [set this field again](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/metadata#content-type)?